# node js - refused to apply css (MIME type text/html)

Tags: css, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to implement my css in my html with nodeJS, Express and socket.io but i got the error: 
**'Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/index.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.'**

**Note**: I only got the error displaying the css files when i run in my localhost:8000 (Node.js) but not in my normal index.html file.

*here is my config in index.js*

```
var app = express()
   .use(SocketIOFileUpload.router)
   .get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
   })
```

*here is my files structure*

> - style
>
>   - style.css
> - images
> - lib
> - node_modules 
>     index.html 
>     appConfig.js 
>     index.js

So far, what i did is:

- i change my css script from

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"/>` into `type="text/html"` : it did remove the error but my css still have not applied in the html

- checked the spelling of my css file name: no issue on the name or the css path

i have search all over the internet, but nothing helps. It might be i configured it wrongly since i am not really familiar with the config, but i don't have any ideas. Any helps or hints area really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to display your css files in the website? That is not a common practice.

Comment: Duplicated : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240603/nodejs-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240603/nodejs-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type)

Answer (score 1):

Can you list your directory structure here? The initial error is that you wanted to apply css to your html file but the css file when returned by node had a mine type of html. When applying style if you manually set the mine time to html for a css file, it’s certainly not going to work. What is your css file name and path? A speculation I have is that your app is not configured to serve the css file. When asked for the css file, the server is probably responding with a 404 which is a mime type of html, hence the error. Look at your nose console logs when you load the page for a 404 for the css. You’ll have to show us where/how you are serving static files for us to help any further. 
Yep you have the style.css inside of style, you need to set the static directory accordingly. Here is a reference

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

taken from https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
In your case you can wrap your images and  styles folder under public and then use the given example. In production however, you will want to serve static files using a reverse proxy like Nginx.

Comment: Hi thanks for the responses, i edited my post. I added the files structure, hope it gives you some ideas. @Khanal

Comment: @AliffM. Did this help you?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, ive been busy with other project, yes i manage to get it applied on my localhost but instead of .use i use .get to get the .css file. thanks a lot for your hint! :)) you may check below how i do it! :D @khanal

Comment: Thanks, looks like the literal addition of the middleware I suggested fixes your problem. Although if you only copied the .css files into public folder without changing the html file linking the style href of style/style.css should not have worked. The folder structure should have either been public/style.css or the html should have been updated to href=style.css. Could you post the update here as well so that others who run into this issue can see the difference? I’d suggest posting the dir structure and the html file section where you attach the css for reference.

Answer (score 0):

my fix was
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

Comment: You could explain in detail why this solution worked, especially how it differs from the other app.use in the other answer.  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review due to you being a new contributor.  Your answer is appreciated & useful.  This comment is to help a good answer become an excellent answer.